# notepad++ - How to search multi-line values with extended options

Tags: notepad++

I am using Notepad++ version 6.6.9, and I have the following text in my HTML file...

```
...
<li>The National School Lunch Program: Is it Historic Legislation?<br />
<br />
</li>
...
```

When I do a find, and select "Extend" and type in...

```
<br /> \n<br />
```

...It finds nothing.  What am I doing wrong?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you use '\r\n' to find a new line instead just '\n'. Also make sure to include the correct number of spaces in your search string if any are expected.